# How do I loop my animated products using vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tailwind-css

Hello dear stackoverflow users. I need to make image transitions using vue .js as in the site I mentioned in the link. it will come from the left and sit in the middle and disappear at the top right in the middle.my problem here is that when I come to the last product, it comes back from the top right, what I need to do is to always keep 2 products in the bottom left.

example website:
https://polite-hill-00eb08f10.1.azurestaticapps.net/

My code:

```css
/* import font - MONTSERRAT */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap");
html {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body .writing-vertical {
  -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
      -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl;
          writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}

body .outline-text::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1px;
  top: 1px;
  content: attr(data-text);
  color: white;
  z-index: -1;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
}

body .outline-text-rl::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  top: 1px;
  content: attr(data-text);
  color: white;
  z-index: -1;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
}

.product {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: 1s all;
  transition: 1s all;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.product.centerProduct {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.product.pastProduct {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 100%);
          transform: translate(-100%, 100%);
}

.product.upcomingProduct {
  -webkit-transform: translate(9999%, -999%);
          transform: translate(9999%, -999%);
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .outline-text::after {
    left: 3px !important;
    top: 5px !important;
  }
  .outline-text-rl::after {
    left: -3px !important;
    top: 5px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/custom.css">
      <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app" class="fixed top-0 left-0 max-w-full max-h-screen min-h-screen min-w-full">
        <div v-for="(product,index) in products" :key="index"
            :class="activeProduct == product.id ? 'centerProduct' : activeProduct > product.id ? 'upcomingProduct' : activeProduct < product.id ? 'pastProduct' : '' "
            class="product max-w-[350px] h-[60vh] w-full">
            <div :style="{backgroundImage: 'url('+ product.src +')',backgroundSize:'cover',backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',backgroundPosition: 'center center'}"
                class="w-full h-full">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button @click="prev()">prev</button>
        <button @click="next()">next</button>
    </div>
    <script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    <script>
        const { createApp } = Vue

        createApp({
            data() {
                return {
                    products: [
                        {
                            id: 0,
                            src: "https://via.placeholder.com/1000",
                            name: "URUN 0",
                            color: "red",
                        },
                        {
                            id: 1,
                            src: "https://via.placeholder.com/1000",
                            name: "URUN 1",
                            color: "green",
                        },
                        {
                            id: 2,
                            src: "https://via.placeholder.com/1000",
                            name: "URUN 2",
                            color: "gray",
                        },
                        {
                            id: 3,
                            src: "https://via.placeholder.com/1000",
                            name: "URUN 3",
                            color: "rebeccapurple",
                        },
                        {
                            id: 4,
                            src: "https://via.placeholder.com/1000",
                            name: "URUN 4",
                            color: "yellow",
                        },
                        {
                            id: 5,
                            src: "https://via.placeholder.com/1000",
                            name: "URUN 5",
                            color: "orangered",
                        },
                    ],
                    activeProduct: 2,
                }
            },
            methods: {
                next() {
                    this.activeProduct++
                    if (this.activeProduct >= this.products.length) {
                        this.activeProduct = this.products.length - this.products.length
                    } else {
                        console.log(this.activeProduct);
                    }
                },
                prev() {
                    this.activeProduct--
                    if (this.activeProduct < this.products.length - this.products.length) {
                        this.activeProduct = this.products.length - 1
                        console.log(this.activeProduct);
                    } else {
                        console.log(this.activeProduct);
                    }
                }
            },
        }).mount('#app')
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm still researching, but how can I make it loop from the bottom left instead of coming back from the top right when it comes to the last picture?

Comment: You should try upadting the class of first slide if the index is last. Right now you are only checking next, prev.